# check if a numbers comes before the same number but am not getting any output from the code

Tags: python

```
number =[2,3,4,9,9,5,1]
def checkList(List1):
    for i in range(len(List1 - 1)):

if List1[i] == 9 and List1[i+1] == 9:
            return True
    return false
```

this code does not output any value either true or false, it is suppose to output true if 9 comes after 9 or false if otherwise 
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwm0S.png  this link contain the code and the output

Comment: Please correct the indentation, and tell where you call `checkList` method.

Comment: You immediately return `False` in case the `if` check failed, but that might be a problem with your indentation.

Comment: Start with using `len(List1) - 1` instead of `len(List1 - 1)`. And convert `false` to `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just fixed logical mistakes.

```
number = [2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 1]

def checkList(List1):
    for i in range(len(List1) - 1):
        if List1[i] == 9 and List1[i + 1] == 9:
            return True
    return False

checkList(number)
```

Comment: this is what am having but the console isn't outputting anything, am actually using an online editor for it

Comment: @lookatyouman, it's because this code just execute function without processing it's result. You can pass result of function directly into `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is incorrect. If you wrote it like:

```
def checkList(List1):
    for i in range(len(List1 - 1)):
        if List1[i] == 9 and List1[i+1] == 9:
            return True
        return False
```

Then it means that from the moment the `if` check fails, it will return `False`. So that means that if the first two items are not both `9`, the `if` fails, but *in* your `for` loop, you then return `False`, and you never let your program look at the remaining elements.

You furthermore should use `len(List1)-1`, not `len(List1-1)`, since you can not  subtract a number from a list.

You can fix this by moving the `return False` out of the `for` loop:

```
def checkList(List1):
    for i in range(len(List1)-1):
        if List1[i] == 9 and List1[i+1] == 9:
            return True
    return False
```

That being said, you can solve this in a more elegant way by using `zip(..)` to iterate both on a list that list shifted one position:

```
from itertools import islice

def checkList(iterable):
    return any(x == y == 9 for x, y in zip(iterable, islice(iterable, 1, None)))
```

For example:

```
>>> checkList([2,3,4,9,9,5,1])
True
```

Comment: @lookatyouman: where do you instruct it to generate output? You understand there is a difference between `return` and `print(..)`?